# Can one avoid argument mismatch in Java when using "? extends" in generic declaration?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I'm trying to make a function that processes sorted lists of (comparable) elements. I'm therefore using the generic `<T extends List<? extends Comparable>>`, which works will as long as I don't need any list-specific operations that require `<? extends Comparable>` as input. But in the code snippet below (simplest example: computing the intersection of two sorted lists) the line `C.add((Comparable)(A.get(posA)));` is rejected by the compiler, claiming that `add` needs argument `? extends Comparable`, which `Comparable` apparently is not.

```
public static <T extends List<? extends Comparable>> T intersect (T A, T B) {
    T C = (T) A.getClass().newInstance();
    int posA = 0;
    int posB = 0;
    while(posA<A.size()&&posB<B.size()) {
        if (A.get(posA).compareTo(B.get(posB))>0) posB++;
        else if (A.get(posA).compareTo(B.get(posB))<0) posA++;
        else if (A.get(posA).equals(B.get(posB))) {
            C.add((Comparable)(A.get(posA)));
            posA++; posB++;
        }
    }
    return C;
}
```

How should I tell the compiler that `A.get(posA)` is of valid type `? extends Comparable`? Apparently casting doesn't work, and I would like the routine to accept and return lists of arbitrary comparables (Integer, String, custom objects, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't you notice all the unsafe type statements in your code, which multiple unsafe casts ?
You have really many of them. It often means that the overall approach is not the correct one.

In fact things are not so complicated if you learn how generics work in Java.
That could help you :

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html

Here are the main things that you should consider according to your actual code : 
1) Don't use raw type such as `List<? extends Comparable>>`. `Comparable` is a generic class.
2) You cannot add anything but `null` in a List declared `List<? extends Foo>`, that is using a upper bounded wildcard.   The last one allows to make the List covariant : accepting Foo and any subclass but with the previous limitation. So you don't want to use that.
3) You can instantiate a generic `ArrayList` without the need to declare the generic method type `T` for the `ArrayList`. Using `T` for the `Comparable` type will do things really simpler.
4) You want to avoid reflection as much as possible.

By following these ideas you could write a code that could look like :

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> intersect (List<T> A, List<T> B) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();       
    int posA = 0;
    int posB = 0;
    while(posA<A.size()&&posB<B.size()) {
        if (A.get(posA).compareTo(B.get(posB))>0) posB++;
        else if (A.get(posA).compareTo(B.get(posB))<0) posA++;
        else if (A.get(posA).equals(B.get(posB))) {
            list.add(A.get(posA));
            posA++; posB++;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

> That was my original approach, but the problem here is that not every
>   that the intersection of two non-ArrayList Lists will be an ArrayList
>   here.

The type of the List will not be known at compile time if you declare `List` for the parameter. So you will unavoidably finish with unsafe casts.
For example :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Comparable<T>, L extends List<T>> L intersect(L A, L B)  {

    if (A.getClass() != B.getClass()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("not same type between ...");
    }
    List<T> list = A.getClass()
                    .newInstance(); // uncheck

    int posA = 0;
    int posB = 0;
    while (posA < A.size() && posB < B.size()) {
        if (A.get(posA)
             .compareTo(B.get(posB)) > 0)
            posB++;
        else if (A.get(posA)
                  .compareTo(B.get(posB)) < 0)
            posA++;
        else if (A.get(posA)
                  .equals(B.get(posB))) {
            list.add(A.get(posA));
            posA++;
            posB++;
        }
    }
    return (L) list; // uncheck
}
```

Comment: That was my original approach, but the problem here is that not every that the intersection of two non-ArrayList Lists will be an ArrayList here. Ideally, I'd have the return type be the same as the input, i.e. if A and B are LinkedLists, then the returned C should be a LinkedList.

Comment: Ok. I updated to provide a way to solve the issue according to the constraints that you have.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! The updated version works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical generics problem.

You are saying that you accept every list of Objects that extend Comparable.

Therefore, it would be perfectly fine of another method would pass a List to your method.

Of course, you shouldn't be allowed to add a Number to that List in your code, even though it would extend Comparable!

You could fix this problem on your code by adding another generic parameter to your method Signature instead of "?". Then you could cast to that parameter in your code.

Comment: I can't seem to get this working with an extra parameter, without changing the syntax of my function (which has to be `.intersect(List<>,List<>)` returning a `List<>` of the same object type as the two input lists). Can you point me to an example where/how this is done?

Comment: Of course I could start out with 
`public static <T extends Comparable> List<T> intersect (List<T> A, List<T> B) { List<T> C = new ArrayList<T>();` but that would require me to hard pick the list type. Ideally, I'd not specify the list type here (for lists this is not so important, but for the similar operator for Sets it would be important that the intersection of two `TreeSet`s returns a `TreeSet` while the intersection of two `HashSet`s returns a `HashSet`).